# addEvent type mismatch IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, type-mismatch, attachevent

I am getting a TYPE: Mismatch error in IE8 with the following code.

```
    function showTabs() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].style.display = "inline-block";
        if (tabs[i]) {
            console.log(tabs[i] + " " + i);
        }
    }
}

function showThumbBoxes() {
    for (var i = 0; i < thumbsContainers.length; i++) {
        thumbsContainers[i].style.display = "block";
        if (thumbsContainers[i]) {
            console.log(thumbsContainers[i] + " " + i);
        }
    }
}

function loadImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < lazyImages.length; i++) {
        if (lazyImages[i].getAttribute("data-src")) {
            lazyImages[i].src = lazyImages[i].getAttribute("data-src");
            if (lazyImages[i]) {
                console.log(lazyImages[i] + " " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}

function hideContainers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddenContainers.length; i++) {
        hiddenContainers[i].style.display = "none";
        if (hiddenContainers[i]) {
            console.log(hiddenContainers[i] + " " + i);
        }
    }
}

function setUpPage() {
    showTabs();
    showThumbBoxes();
    loadImages();
    hideContainers();
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", setUpPage())
} else {
    window.attachEvent("load", setUpPage()); <<< Here seems to be causing issues.
}
```

I have steppped through the code and it goes through everything correctly and everything gets loaded to the page. After I step through the last curly brace of setUpPage function, it is back on the `attachEvent("load", setUpPage());` When I click step through again, I get the mismatch error. Not sure what is going on but because of the error the rest of my script will not load.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `attachEvent` you need to add on + name of the event, so the event will be called `onload`

**UPDATE**

Also the second parameter of both of the event listeners, are callbacks, so they get executed when the event is triggered.
To be able to achieve that, you need to remove the parenthesis of the function call.

Comment: This solves that problem, and leads me into another. Would you be able to help with that?

Comment: So now the eventlistener is working, I find that when I click on the element it is returning undefined in IE8, it is working in everything else. I looked a bit deeper and it seems in IE8 the element is actually referring to the body node rather than the node being clicked on. I think it is becuase I am using the "This" keyword.

Comment: Yeah, that will be it, in that context `this` refers to the window object.

Comment: Only in IE8 though, strangely. > IE8 and other browsers get the correct element.

Comment: That's weird, can you give me an example, because I cannot see any `this` on your code above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184415/discussion-between-shemiroth-and-alejandro-garcia-anglada).